# fitting a cumulative line to histogram with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I created the histogram below:

[image: sample histogram]

and was wondering if instead of plotting the whole graph (in blue) I could just plot the top edge (in black)?

or just fit the line to match the top of the distribution?

my code is:

```
plt.hist(histogramData, bins=200, normed=True, cumulative=True, edgecolor='b', facecolor='None')
```

I tried removing 'edgecolor' and 'facecolor' but it does not seem to work...

Thank for your help!

Comment: Would also be interesting to be able to plot both together perhaps. Like [this in d3.js](http://bl.ocks.org/daluu/5f67cefcf26483c6b555).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think pylabs histogram codes uses numpys `np.histogram()` function, yielding bins and counts; so if you use that together wit the standard `plot()` command, you are done (just remember to also do the `np.cumsum()`on the counts of the `np.histogram()` for the cummulative look).

Edit: 
Regarding the comment, I quote from the `numpy.histogram()` [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html):

> **Returns**:
>
> *hist* : array
>
> The values of the histogram. See normed and weights for a description of the possible semantics.
>
> *bin edges* : array of dtype float
>
> Return the bin edges (length(hist)+1).

Thus, to plot your data in the desired way:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(data, bins=200)
plt.plot( bins[:-1], np.cumsum(hist) )
```

or if you want to be more precise, you could even put the data values in the bin center:

```
offset = bins[1:]-bins[:-1]
plt.plot( bins[:-1]+offset, np.cumsum(hist) )
```

Comment: thanks. i tried it and it looks like the number of bins and counts is different (200 and 201) and I cant plot the data...

Comment: @kate88 indeed, the bins are the values of the edges of the bins, not the center values (see `np.hist` documentation). As you can see I do therefore not take all the bins but calculate the bin's center position for a point plot.